# FacesContext.addMessage() does not show message in p:messages

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss, facescontext

i have a managed bean with a method that add a message like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileMB implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2843716026642626725L;

private UploadedFile file;
private boolean enabled = false;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void upload() {

    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("test");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

}
```

i call this method from xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title></title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Show" type="button" actionListener="#{fileMB.upload}" />
</h:form>
 <h:form id="frmMensajes">
    <p:messages id="mensajes" showDetails="false"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

but i cant see the "test" message, i added the managed bean declaration in faces-config too, what could i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `autoUpdate` attribute.

Something like this : `<p:messages id="mensajes" showDetails="false" autoUpdate="true" />`

According to the documentation :

> When auto update is enabled, messages component is updated with each ajax request automatically

Comment: There's one more cause, but OP will discover that himself once he figures that action method is actually not invoked (or else it's just a red herring in the question as result of fiddling).

Comment: Thank u all contributors, i only needed to add autoUpdate and it works perfectly! tnxs again. i forget to add parenthesis to the method actionListener="#{fileMB.upload()}" Primefaces doesnt works without them

Answer (score -1):

Try one of the following inside the first `h:form`

1) `p:messages globalOnly="true"`

2) `p:message for=<command button id>` and add `id` to the commanbutton

Comment: Sorry, none of both suggestions make sense. Next time first test yourself before doing off as an answer.